# Is there an Attribute I can use in my class to tell DataGridView not to create a column for it when bound to a List<MyClass>

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, properties, attributes

I have a class like this:

```
private class MyClass {
  [DisplayName("Foo/Bar")]
  public string FooBar { get; private set; }
  public string Baz { get; private set; }      
  public bool Enabled;
}
```

When I create a `List<MyClass>` and assign it to the `DataSource` of a `DataGridView`, the grid shows me two columns, "Foo/Bar" and "Baz". This is what I want to happen.

It currently works because Enabled is a field, not a property - DataGridView will only pick up properties. However, this is a dirty hack.

I would like to make Enabled a property too, but still hide it on the DataGridView.

I know I can manually delete the column after binding.. but that's not ideal.

Is there an attribute similar to DisplayName, that I can tag a property with? Something like `[Visible(false)]` ?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

[`[Browsable(false)]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.aspx) will hide a property from a `DataGridView`.

> A visual designer typically displays in the Properties window those
>   members that either have no browsable attribute or are marked with the
>   BrowsableAttribute constructor's browsable parameter set to true.
>   These members can be modified at design time. Members marked with the
>   BrowsableAttribute constructor's browsable parameter set to false are
>   not appropriate for design-time editing and therefore are not
>   displayed in a visual designer. The default is true.

Comment: That's funny, in my eyes [Bindable(false)] should work and Browsable (according to the help) only defines if a property is shown in the PropertyGrid. But Bindable(false) is ignored by the DataGridView.

Comment: I agree, but after reading (and re-reading) the Framework Design Guidelines (http://www.amazon.com/Framework-Design-Guidelines-Conventions-Development/dp/0321246756), I have found that the designers didn't always follow their own rules (and sometimes did things that didn't make sense).

Comment: All these controls use `System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor`, and hence they use the same logic for including/excluding members.  The `ComponentModel` classes are customizable, but doing so is rare because it's so much work.

Answer (score 10):

I've been blissfully unaware that the `System.ComponentModel` decorator attributes like `BrowsableAttribute` and it's kin were related to anything other than binding to a `PropertyGrid`. (*facepalm*) I like C-Pound Guru's approach because it allows you to keep your GUI more loosely coupled than what I've done in the past.

Just for a different perspective, the approach I've used for a long time is to pre-define columns in your DataGridView, either programatically or through the Form Designer.  When you do this, you can set each column's `DataPropertyName` to the name of your property.  The only trick is that you need to set the DataGridView's `AutoGenerateColumns` property to false otherwise the DGV will completely ignore your manually created columns.  Note that, for whatever reason, the `AutoGenerateColumns` property is hidden from the Form Designer's Property Grid...no idea *why*.  The one advantage I see to this approach is that you can pre-set the column formatting and such - you don't have to bind and then go tweak column rendering/sizing settings.

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
_DGV.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn textColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
textColumn.DataPropertyName = "FooBar";
textColumn.HeaderText = "Foo/Bar"; // may not need to do this with your DisplayNameAttribute
_DGV.Columns.Add(textColumn);
textColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
textColumn.DataPropertyName = "Baz";

List<MyClass> data = GetMyData();
_DGV.DataSource = data;
```

Comment: I am glad to see that I am not the only one who is excluded from accessing the `AutoGenerateColumns` property via the Form Designer.

Comment: I'd certainly consider this the best answer. One single code line that does exactly all the job instead of refactoring all my custom classes....