# Fill just some DataView columns with IEnumerable

Tags: c#, winforms, ienumerable

I have a method which returns an IEnumerable of some custom type.

```
 public IEnumerable<_Persona> RegresaBusquedaPersona(string nombres)
        {
            return context.personas.Where(x => x.Nombres.Contains(nombres) ||
                                            x.ApellidoP.Contains(nombres) ||
                                            x.ApellidoM.Contains(nombres))
                                            .Select(x => new _Persona
                                            {
                                                Id = x.IDPersona,
                                                Nombres = x.Nombres,
                                                ApellidoP = x.ApellidoP,
                                                ApellidoM = x.ApellidoM,
                                                FechaNacimiento = x.FechaNacimiento
                                            });
        }
```

Even when _Persona has some other properties I just want to return the properties chosen in the method.

The problem is that when I fill my DataView with results, properties that aren't set they are being displayed and I don't want this, so I manually make these columns not visible.

```
public void LLenarDataView(IEnumerable<_Persona> personas)
        {
            _listaPersonas.DataSource = personas;
            _listaPersonas.Columns["Sexo"].Visible = false;
            _listaPersonas.Columns["Rfc"].Visible = false;
            _listaPersonas.Columns["Curp"].Visible = false;
            _listaPersonas.Columns["EstadoCivil"].Visible = false;
            _listaPersonas.Columns["Direccion"].Visible = false;
            _listaPersonas.Columns["Cp"].Visible = false;
            _listaPersonas.Columns["Delegacion"].Visible = false;
            _listaPersonas.Columns["Email"].Visible = false;
            _listaPersonas.Columns["Telefono"].Visible = false;
            _listaPersonas.Columns["Celular"].Visible = false;
            _listaPersonas.Columns["Empresa"].Visible = false;
            _listaPersonas.AutoResizeColumns();
        }
```

Is there a simpler way of doing the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dataview automatically generates columns based on data from your class. Neat way to hide columns is to use "Browsable" attribute in your class like this:

```
[Browsable(false)]
public string MyString { get;set;}
```

See this so [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152951/c-sharp-hide-a-property-in-datagridview-with-datasource) for reference.