# Is there a way to customize the columns of List created with SQL using BindingSource and dataGridView?

Tags: c#, database, datagridview, bindingsource

I am making a windows app that generates words with the letters the user enters. I use a database with 50k words. For each word, I compare the letters entered by the user with the number of letters in the Table and filter the word according to its suitability. To make it more understandable, I will show the row of a word in the table below.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgyM9.png
Since I compare all the rows in the table, I have to say "select * from table" in the SQL command, so I cannot customize the column there.
I want only Word to appear as a column in the dataGridView. I indicate it in the image below. I tried using BindingSource.Filter but failed.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOsnv.png

I am sharing the code part of the app that I have a problem with.

```
namespace kelimeApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        BindingSource kelimesBindingSource = new BindingSource();
        List<Kelime> kelimes = new List<Kelime>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AlbumsDAO albumsDAO = new AlbumsDAO();

            kelimes = albumsDAO.getAllKelimes(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text,
                textBox3.Text, textBox4.Text, textBox5.Text, textBox6.Text, textBox7.Text, textBox8.Text, textBox9.Text, textBox10.Text, Convert.ToInt32(birNUD.Value), Convert.ToInt32(ikiNUD.Value), Convert.ToInt32(ucNUD.Value), birHarfTB.Text, ikiHarfTB.Text, ucHarfTB.Text);

            kelimesBindingSource.DataSource = kelimes;                        
            dataGridView1.DataSource = kelimesBindingSource;                                
        }

        
    }
}
```

```
namespace kelimeApp
{
    public class Kelime
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public String Word { get; set; }

        public int Length { get; set; }

        public int A { get; set; }
        ...
        ...
        public int Z { get; set; }
```

Comment: Simply precreate that one column in the datagridview and don't use autocreate for the columns? See the AutoGenerateColumns property.

Comment: Additionaly the SQL has nothing to do with the Kelime class. You may have mapped your data somehow in your AlbumsDAO but nothing should prevent you that Kelime must look exactly like what you retrieved from the DB. Or map a Kelime onto another class with less properties.

Comment: Do you mean https://stackoverflow.com/a/1152975/14171304 ?