# C# NHibernate QueryOver select multiple Properties

Tags: c#, nhibernate, datagridview

In my C# application I use NHibernate to get all rooms from my database table 'room'.

```
using (ISession pSession = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
            {
                IList<Room> roomList = pSession.QueryOver<Room>().
                                                Where(x => x.FloorID == 3).
                                                .List();
            }
```

The table 'room' and also my Mapping class (Room.cs) contains  lets say the following properties:

```
roomID
hash
date
identifier
```

I have a DataGridView which should display my table entries from the database: the code is:

```
 roomDataGridView.DataSource = roomList;
```

That works fine so far. But now I decide that I dont want to show all the properties from the Room class, I only want to display

```
roomID
identifier
```

I tried the following:

```
roomDataGridView.DataSource = listOfRoomPropertiesForCurrentFloor.Select(x => new {x.Identifier, x.RoomID });
```

Unfortunately this does not work...nothing gets printed in my DataGridView.

Question: How can I store all properties from the room table in my room model BUT ONLY show TWO of the four properties in the DataGridView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your column names are defined in the DataGridView and create the object, basically assign the x.Identifier to the name "Identifier" so it can be picked up and call the `ToList()` function

```
roomDataGridView.DataSource = listOfRoomPropertiesForCurrentFloor
                              .Select(x => new {Identifier = x.Identifier, RoomID = x.RoomID }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Expecting that DataGridView attribute `AutoCreateColumns` should be set to true. There are already answers:

- [c# Hide a property in datagridview with datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1152975/1679310)
- [Is there an Attribute I can use in my class to tell DataGridView not to create a column for it when bound to a List](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1066949/1679310)

Extract:

> Mark the property which should not be displayed with an attribute `[Browsable(false)]`