# How to hide DataGridView Column?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, attributes

i have a simple class like below. And a `List<Person>`. I bind this list to the `DataGridView` in the Form.

```
class Person {
  public int ID {get; set;}
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Surname { get; set; }
  [DisplayName("Birth Date")]
  public DateTime BDate { get; set; }
}
```

With Attribute `DisplayName` i can change column header text.
My question is
**Is there any Attribute to hide the `ID` Property of the `Person`?**

**AND SECOND QUESTION (UPDATED)**
Is there any Attribute to change the order of this properties when bind the list to the grid?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an Attribute I can use in my class to tell DataGridView not to create a column for it when bound to a List<MyClass>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066907/is-there-an-attribute-i-can-use-in-my-class-to-tell-datagridview-not-to-create-a)

Comment: You can set the Column's `DisplayIndex` after binding, but I don't think there's an attribute for it

Answer (score 2):

You can use:  [Browsable(false)]

```
class Person {
  [Browsable(false)]
  public int ID {get; set;}
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Surname { get; set; }
  [DisplayName("Birth Date")]
  public DateTime BDate { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is probably what you are looking for
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c24a0d7.aspx

Comment: is Visibility an Attribute?